# will a correlation between a percentage variable and a numerical variable work?

Tags: correlation, percentage

I am trying to conduct a simple correlation analysis between a group of variable, however I have a number of these variables in percentage change (or percentage yield) form and the others in strictly numerical prices. I was wondering whether it is possible to find the correlation coefficients between a percentage variable and a numerical variable?

I have tried with the data as it is as well as with all variables in some percentage return format with varying results, hence my current confusion!

The data I am working with relates to the prices of stocks, gold etc and the percentage yield/change of bonds and CPI %change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you mean that you correlated the price of a stock (level) w/ another variable & the percent change in the price of a stock w/ the other variable, & got different results, that is to be expected, b/c they are different questions. Can you clarify?

Comment: ok so an example of what I'm having trouble with is when I'm correlating the price of a stock (price/number) eg. FTSE 100/S&P 500  with a percentage variable eg. the inflation rate. Will such a correlation work? (as one is a percentage and the other is a number). Sorry my stats knowledge isn't the best!